When does a system have a steady state? (based on the system's transition matrix)
I have seen it said that a system, partly described by transition matrix, $T$, has no steady state if $T^2$ has any zeros.
When you apply this to a directed network, having zeros in a transition matrix equates to no flow between two states. Like if
$$\pmatrix{0.1 & 0\\ 0.9 & 1}$$
and the first column correspond to the initial state being A, and the second column is the initial state being B. The zero in this matrix means that there is no way to transition from state A to state B.
Even as I am writing this, I am probably butchering the concept of "state" - hence why I am here, to correct my muddled thinking.
But this isn't $T^2$, it is just $T$. Nevertheless, $T^2$ is also going to yield a zero in the top right.
Can someone explain why this is true? That if $T^2$ has zeros that it means this system has no steady state?
